# How to make asp.net routing use a different application path

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, routes

In an asp.net mvc application, I would like to be able to generate views, where the routing engine will create all URLs that point to a different site, i.e. change the application path.

Comment: More info needed - example of urls would be great.

Comment: Have you thought about using a URL rewrite product outside of your application instead? Maybe something like this http://www.isapirewrite.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't be done with standard routes. Routing is intended to generate URLs within the current application. After all, if you generate URLs outside your application, routing has no idea that something will be there to match the route.

You either can write your own custom routes that derive from Route (or RouteBase) and do the logic yourself, or use IIS URL Rewriting.